# How to update remote database using FTP or File System publishing method using code first migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ftp, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have deployed my ASP.NET MVC application using FTP publishing method, application was working fine until i republished it after making some changes, i used code first migration to update database locally and it was working fine. When i published it again i am getting the error saying:"Model backing a DB Context has changed; Consider Code First Migrations". When using web deploy publishing method there is no problem database is updated, problem is when using FTP or File System publishing.

I would like to know how can remote database be updated when using FTP or File System publishing method. My current host doesn't offer web deploy publishing, is either i use FTP or File system.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the File System publishing method and happen to make changes to your Models, then you will have to re-publish your project and just replace it with the one existing on the Server.

Comment: Thanks Nickson, but i do not want to loose data on remote database when ever i made changes to models. Can you explain how can i upload project using file system and not loose the data in database?

Comment: Whenever you publish your project as long as the connection string is defined in your webconfig. No matter what changes you make, your database is never affected. Unless you make changes to your model then on the Package Manger Console you'll have to run   'add-migration "name' then "Update-database -verbose'.

Comment: Thanks again Nikson, i did that locally, i add migration, and then update database and application working fine on locally on visual studio. Problem is when i have to upload it to remote server, migration is not being run like when using web deploy publishing method. I think something must done in remote server so that it run migration and accept models i have added, when using FTP or File System. After publishing i change the connection string to connect to remote database.

Comment: Within your webconfig. Before adding migration and updating, ensure the connection string points to the remote server. That way, the database will be deployed automatically.

Comment: OK, i will try that.

Comment: Share your connection string

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, all i have to do was to add the following code in DbContext like:

```
    public InvoiceContext()
        : base("InvoiceContext") 
    {

    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new 
    MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<InvoiceContext, 
    Identity2Example.Migrations.InvoiceContext.Configuration>());  

   }

   I hope it will also help somebody.
```